# how to make dynamic field creation capability in openerp module?

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

Hi I have created an openerp module using Python (eclipse) . I want to add a feature in my form so that admin will be able to create his own fields whenever and whatever he wants . I needed some guidance of how this will be done . As I am new to openerp , any help will be good to me . Thanks

Hopes for advice

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any easy way of doing this.  When OpenERP connects to a database it sets up a registry containing all models and all the fields and as part of this, loads the fields into the database, performs database refactoring etc.  The idea is that it is simple to inherit existing models and add your fields that way but it does require coding.

I have done something similar where:

1. I predefined some fields on your model (field1, intfield1, charfield1 etc.).
2. Provide a model/form so the admin can say use intfield1 and give it a label of 'My Value'
3. Override fields_view_get on your model and change the XML to include your field with the correct label.

But this is tricky to get right.  You will want to spend some time learning the elementtree module to do the XML manipulation in the `fields_view_get`.